# "Expected params.Attributes[Enabled] to be a string" when calling setEndpointAttributes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I just got this error and solved it and figured I'd share this obscure bit of knowledge.

> Expected params.Attributes[Enabled] to be a string

when calling `setEndpointAttributes`

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {
  Attributes: {
    Enabled: true,
  },
  EndpointArn: "...",
};

sns.setEndpointAttributes(params, function(err, resp){
  // err.message => "Expected params.Attributes[Enabled] to be a string"
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {
  Attributes: {
    Enabled: "true",
    //       ^    ^ Quote the variable
  },
  EndpointArn: "...",
};

sns.setEndpointAttributes(params, function(err, resp){
  // ...
});
```